# What is a one-parameter Newton's method?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

The Newton's method that I know is defined as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

However, I've recently encountered [a paper](http://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/JAM/Volume2012/294086.pdf) that talks about a ***one-parameter family of Newton's method*** (page 4, equation 2.8), defined as follows:

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)-pf(x_n)}$$

What is this $p$ parameter in the equation above? Why is it not present in the first equation? What is this parameter useful for? What is that *one-parameter* Newton's method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"One-parameter family" simply means that one real parameter, $p$, appears in the definition. That method is simply a generalization of Newton's method exposed in the first equation; you can't derive it from the first.

The classical Newton's method has slower convergence when $f'(\alpha)=0$, $\alpha$ being the sought solution: the purpose of this generalization is obtaining a Newton-like method that does not encounter trouble when $f'(\alpha)=0$. I hope this solves your issues!

Comment: Thank you for the response. How does introducing the $p$ makes the method faster than the classical one? What value should $p$ have to make it work better?

Comment: This is explained in your paper. Check around Equation (2.9), there is an asymptotic expression for the error which involves $p$.

Comment: So as to speed up the root finding and get the second-order (quadratic) convergence we need to find a $p$ that will make the denominator the largest one? Could you please include in your response a brief explanation how this is calculated from the error equation (I haven't seen before the asymptotic expressions)?

Comment: It's the first time I see that generalization, too, so I can't give you more information than what can be read in the paper. Have you checked reference [2]?

Comment: I don't have the access to this [2] paper. But basically, is my assumption correct that $p$ is supposed to make the denominator the largest one?

Comment: I can only answer based on what I read in the paper. If the error is $(p-c_2)e_n^2+O(n^3)$, then you minimize it (asymptotically) with $p=c_2$. Its expression involves second derivatives and may not be readily available, so you could use an approximation. That is the asymptotic convergence speed, though, which is often irrelevant: once you are close to the solution, a couple of iterations get you there anyway in practice. What one would like to minimize is the initial transient phase in which the error does not decrease, and as far as I know it's an open problem for every Newton-like method.